# How to get headers parameters value using postman to php?

Tags: php, postman

i want to get all header parameters value which i used in postman headers tab.

i passed value in header like : 'lancode','deviceId', etc..

i try

```
$lancode = $request->header('lancode');
```

but this code is does not work for me.. other solution please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use

```
$getHeaders = apache_request_headers();
```

and then you can store header value like

```
$lancode = $getHeaders['lancode'];
```

it's work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can get specific header with

```
`$_SERVER["HTTP_" . strtoupper(str_replace("-","_",$header_name))];`
```

In your case use `$_SERVER['HTTP_LANCODE'];`

**For example** set a header `test` with `sss`, then the `print_r($_SREVER)`, output

```
Array
(
    [HTTP_TEST] => ssss
    ...
)
```

**Note:** updace your header name, then replace `-` with `_` then append `HTTP_` to the header name when access from `$_SERVER` variable.

---

[rfc3875: 4.1.18. Protocol-Specific Meta-Variables](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html)

> Meta-variables with names beginning with "HTTP_" contain values
>   read    from the client request header fields, if the protocol used is
>   HTTP.    The HTTP header field name is converted to upper case, has
>   all    occurrences of `"-"` replaced with `"_"` and has "HTTP_" prepended
>   to    give the meta-variable name.

Comment: How you use it?

Comment: $_SERVER['myparam'];

Comment: You need to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_MYPARAM'];` to access it.

Comment: my parameter name is : DEVICE_ID how can i use?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_ID']`

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER)` here